# C# Application Domain Call Backs

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, appdomain

i am working on a WPF application that will be used to host other assemblies. I am currently developing the app in visual studio 2010 with .net 4. My question here is once i run a new application domain from the main host thread how can i do a call back to the host thread and basically give control back to the host gui without closing the program that is running on the application domain, just hiding the that program gui so that it can later be reused by the user. i see that you can make callbacks to domains that you create from the host thread by using the name that was assigned to them, but how can i make a call back to the host thread since it is not an app domain that i created and named ???

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Please provide some code: what do you have for now? Related: [Sharing data between AppDomains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11665093/1352471)

Comment: Sorry but i dont really have any thing right now i am still just trying to figure out how to get the app domain to run correctly. Maybe some basic example would help, just trying to learn some of this before i actually get to the point in my program where i will actually need it.        Thank you for responding to my question, really appreciate you taking the time to read this.