# How to run code in another AppDomain? I need to sandbox my IronPython code

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, sandbox

I have some IronPython code, and im passing variables to it and want to receive a result from python. I managed to get the result from IronPython when i create an engine in the current domain:

```
ScriptEngine pyEngine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine()
```

then i just take the result like that:

```
var result = this.pyScope.GetVariable("ObiektMS").code_1_1_1("II");
```

However, I need it sandboxed so im creating an AppDomain with restricted permissions and running the engine in it:

```
ScriptEngine pyEngine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine(newDomain)
```

But this time when i try to get the result in the samy way i get

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in PythonTimeTests.exe
```

Is it because my "result" variable is in a different domain and the result from ironpython has to be serialized?

Is it possible to create a variable in the new domain?
I want my program to do this:

1.Read a dictionary from a file.

2.Create a new domain with restrictions and pass the dictionary to it.

3.Do work in iron python by calling python functions from c#(all in restricted domain)

4.Return the results to the unrestricted domain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - cross domain variables are serialized between domains unless they inherit from MarshallByRefObject as explained here [Sharing data between AppDomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206961/sharing-data-between-appdomains)

Your second question is "can I ... do some C# stuff" - yes; you can do anything you want in an AppDomain. You just need to follow the rules on AppDomain data transfer in order to pass stuff between AppDomains.